# Bootstrap is not applied to automatically generated cards via php

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I am generating new cards with PHP code, but they do not listen to the grid of bootstrap 4.
Raw html code works fine and displays them like they should be.

```html
<div class="container-fluid padding">
  <div class="row padding">
    <?php foreach ($contacts as $contact): ?>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <div class="card">
                    <?php echo '<img class="card-img-top" src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode( $contact['horse_image'] ).'"/>'; ?>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title"><?=$contact['horse_name']?></h4>
                        <p class="card-text"><?=$contact['short']?></p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
  <hr class="my-4">
</div>
```

This is the code for generated cards from database, it works just fine but bootstrap is not applied on that so it looks very bad [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5QL1.jpg) but it should be looking [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XYAq.jpg)

Is there a way to apply bootstrap after the cards are generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, can't comment yet because of the reputation of 50 :D

In your foreach block is one closing div tag too much ;)

Comment: that worked, thank you very much, i did not see that :D